# Caliburn Micro -- Change Individual Items in BindableCollection

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I am displaying a collection in a listview, and each listview item has its own button for downloading the related pdf.

I want to click the button and display an indeterminate progress bar in it's place.

In my sample project, I'm merely trying to invert the item's download status when I click its button.

My viewmodel code:

```
private BindableCollection<IDownloadable> _downloadables;
public BindableCollection<IDownloadable> Downloadables
{
    get { return _downloadables; }
    set
    {
        _downloadables = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Downloadables);
    }
}

public void Download(IDownloadable item)
{
    item.Downloading = !item.Downloading;
    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Downloadables);
}

public ShellViewModel()
{
    Downloadables = new BindableCollection<IDownloadable>();

    Downloadables.Add(new DownloadString("String"));
    Downloadables.Add(new DownloadString("String"));
    Downloadables.Add(new DownloadString("String"));
}
```

My view:

```
<ListView Name="Downloadables"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Background="White">
                            <ToggleButton Content="{Binding MyString}"
                                          Width="50"
                                          Height="50"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                          cal:Message.Attach="Download($dataContext)"/>
                            <spark:SprocketControl Width="30"
                                                   Height="30"
                                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                   AlphaTicksPercentage="50"
                                                   Interval="60"
                                                   IsIndeterminate="True"
                                                   LowestAlpha="50"
                                                   StartAngle="-90"
                                                   TickColor="LawnGreen"
                                                   TickCount="12"
                                                   TickWidth="3" 
                                                   Visibility="{Binding Downloading, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                        </Grid>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I had imagined that NotifyOfPropertyChanged would tell the collection items to update, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has has nothing to do with collection. The template binds to the item itself. It has no idea about the collection. This means, you need to implement notification ([INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)) in the item itself.